# Find one operator with infinity Hilbert-Schmidt norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\ell_2^n:=\{x=(x_1,\dots, x_n): \|x\|_2<\infty\}$. I try to find a sequence of bounded linear operators $T_n: \ell_2^n\to \ell_2^n$ so that
$$
\frac{\|T_n\|_{HS}}{\|T_n\|}\to \infty
$$
as $n\to \infty$, where $\|\cdot\|_{HS}$ is the Hilbert-Schmidt norm.

My example is that let $\{e_n\}$ be orthonormal basis  of $\ell_2^n$. Define for $x\in \ell_2^n$ by
$$
T_n(x)=n^{-1/3}x.
$$
Then $T_n$ is bounded and
$$
\|T_n\|^2_{HS}=\sum_{j=1}^n\|T_n e_j\|^2=n^{1/3}\to \infty
$$
as $n\to \infty$.

But I am confused about if we can choose $n$ coincide with the dimension $n$?

Comment: Take $T_ n=I_n$.

Comment: I think you must be careful with the indices.I assume you want a sequence of operators $\{T_{i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$, all operating on $\ell^{n}_{2}$, right?

Comment: @bayes2021 Yes, exactly!

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc So that would be $\|T_n\|_{HS}=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n \|I_n e_k\|^2}=\sqrt{n}$?